# float.parsefloat numberformatexception when ontext changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberformatexception

Here is my piece of code where in i am checking edittext input dynamically.

```
al_e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String al_s=s.toString().trim();
            if((Float.parseFloat(al_s)<15)|(Float.parseFloat(al_s)>50)|al_s.equals("")){
                invalid=1;
                al_s="";
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a valid input\nRange [15mm,50mm]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                al_e.setError("Please enter a valid input\nRange [15mm,50mm]");
            }else{
                al=Float.parseFloat(al_s);
            }
        }
    });
```

---

but when i input text in edittext and use backspace to clear the number i get the following exception

```
02-10 09:43:37.186: E/AndroidRuntime(434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 09:43:37.186: E/AndroidRuntime(434): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
02-10 09:43:37.186: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
02-10 09:43:37.186: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:323)
02-10 09:43:37.186: E/AndroidRuntime(434):  at com.example.iolcalci.Second$4.onTextChanged(Second.java:208)
```

---

Searched the forum for similar problem but dint find it. Any help regarding this.I'm a beginner in android development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parseFloat on an empty string.  That is why you are getting a NumberFormatException.

Do something like the following instead.

```
try {
    float num = Float.parseFloat(al_s);
    if (num < 15 || num > 50) {
        // set invalid...
    } else {
        al = num;
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // set invalid...
}
```

Note also that even though your doing `al_s.equals("")` to check for an empty string, it needs to be the first test of the conditional rather than the last.  Otherwise the string will be parsed before the test, causing the `NumberFormatException`.